# Card View применение

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-xml

Надо так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На деле так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если делать кнопку без `CardView`, то она плоская и с углами.

ХМЛ:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:background="#2196f3"
        android:text="Suggest" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Откуда белый прямоугольник внизу?

PS. ставить `match_parent` у кнопки не помогает.

Comment: Задайте высоту как wrap_content

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к чему хД?

Comment: Ко всему. К единственному элементу не имеющему такую высоту. К карточке. Как можно было не понять к чему? 0_о =(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб дело в том, что я перепробовал все вариации, в том то и дело. Этот квадрат внизу торчит постоянно, и я впервые встречаю подобное поведение.

Comment: Удалите android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб жесть, вроде помогло. Не подскажете по верстке ресурсы какие-либо?У меня это хромает все куда сильнее, чем предполагал.
И еще он запускает активити, но оно не запускается по факту о_о

Comment: Только опыт. И запомнить что есть margin padding wrap_content match_parent

Comment: Вообще в любой книге по разработке Android много внимания уделяется верстке, но есть и именно по UI - *Luhani Lehtimaki - Smashing Android UI - 2013*, *Jason Ostrander - Android UI Fundamentals.Develop and Design*. Советую читать книги, а не сайты, в них гораздо лучше все объясняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашей кнопке совсем не обязательно лежать в CardView что бы не быть прямоугольной и плоской.

Создайте файл drawable/roundrect.xml:

```
<shape 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#2196f3" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Пропишите кнопке следующие, что бы закруглить ее углы:

```
android:background="@drawable/roundrect"
```

И следующие, что бы "приподнять", добавить тень:

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключалась в том, что все свойства были заданы кнопке(`button`), а не его контейнеру `CardView` - тем самым я разделял контейнер от содержимого, и они находились вразнобой.

*Из ответа в комментариях (с) ЮрийСПБ*