# Ищу литературу по дизайну и верстке UI под Material design

Tags: java, android, книги

Надоело шляться по сети изучая сомнительные туторы. Хочу найти книжку именно по тонкостям проектирования дизайна. Либо главу в книге, где эта тема раскрыта полностью.

Comment: что вы под тонкостью проектирования подразумеваете?

Comment: [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571112/card-view-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment750188_571112) упоминал пару книжек по UI. Еще можно вспомнить *Greg Nudelman - Android Design Patterns - 2013*. А вообще официальные гайдлайны все тонкости раскрывают полностью.

Answer (score 1):

[Паттерны Андроид](http://unitid.nl/androidpatterns/), устаревший конечно, но очень полезный ресурс.
А если именно под Material, то вам нужно прочитать [Гайдлайны](https://material.google.com/#)